# How to copy a video to NSPasteboard as a file from a local URL (macOS)?

Tags: swift, macos, nspasteboard

I have a mp4 video saved in a folder.
How can i copy the video from my app as a file, in order to paste it in other platforms like Telegram or the Finder to paste it as a new file? 
At the moment this is the function i wrote but it pastes the video only in a iMessage textField.

```
func copyVideo() {
    guard let url = TaskManager.shared.lastVideoURL else { return }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
        pasteboard.declareTypes([kUTTypeMPEG4 as NSPasteboard.PasteboardType], owner: nil)
        print(pasteboard.setData(data, forType: kUTTypeMPEG4 as NSPasteboard.PasteboardType))
    } catch {
        print("error getting data from video \(error)")
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a really bad idea. You are trying to load the whole movie data to memory. It my crash your app.

Comment: What do you suggest, how can i handle this?

Answer (score 3):

After some test I found the **solution**.
This method copies the video as a file:

```
func copyVideo() {      
    guard let url = TaskManager.shared.lastVideoURL else { return }
    if let fileRefURL = (url as NSURL).fileReferenceURL() as NSURL? {
        print(fileRefURL)
        let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
        pasteboard.clearContents()
        pasteboard.writeObjects([fileRefURL])
        pasteboard.setString(fileRefURL.relativeString, forType: .fileURL)
    }
}
```